# react-admin useGetIdentity return only the fullname, id is undefined avatar is undefined

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-admin, loopback

my app is based on tutorial of React-admin and loopback 4 as a backend

I'm trying to get the id of the logged in user, the login mechanisms works well but when i try to access the id of the logged in user it remains undefined.

in my authProvider, my login function is

```
login: ({ username, password }) => {
    const request = new Request(
      process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/users/login',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ email: username, password }),
        headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
      },
    );
    return fetch(request)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
          throw new Error(response.statusText);
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((auth) => {
        localStorage.setItem(
          'auth',
          JSON.stringify({ ...auth, fullName: username }),
        );
      })
      .catch(() => {
        throw new Error('Network error');
      });
  },
```

and I use this in one component:

```
const CurrentUserId = ({ id }) => {
  const { identity, isLoading: identityLoading } = useGetIdentity();

  console.log(identity);
  if (identityLoading) {
    return <span>Loading...</span>;
  } else {
    // find the user_id from the identity
    const user_email = identity.fullName;
    const user_id = identity.id;

    return <span>id: {user_id}</span>;
  }
};
```

but the I console.log returns

```
{id: undefined, fullName: 'xxx@xxxxx.com', avatar: undefined}
```

I followed the instructions presented here
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/AuthProviderWriting.html
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/useGetIdentity.html

any ideas how to retrieve the id?

thanks a lot

Comment: Look at what "auth" server response you are saving in localStorage, apparently the format does not match what is expected when reading in authProvider.getIdentity()

Comment: This is what the console gives me 

    {
    "token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiI[...]exsT0TY",
    "fullName":"nxxx@xxx.com"
    }

I decoded the token on https://jwt.io/ and I got 

    {
      "id": "026fe0f9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b921ae3038f3",
      "name": "Nico",
      "email": "xxx@xxxx.com",
      "iat": 1666257523,
      "exp": 1666279123
    }

So would I need to decode the token in my app? I guess I need to find out how to pass also the id in clear along with the token and email

thanks a lot for your help MaxAlex I will keep digging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you receive a JWT token from the server, you need to decode it and store it like this:

```
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode' 
...
function saveLBToken({ token } : { token: string }) {
  const decoded = jwtDecode(token) 

  if (decoded && typeof decoded === 'object') { 
    sessionStorage.setItem(LB4_TOKEN, JSON.stringify({ token, ...decoded })) 
  } else {
    console.log('Bad LB token:', decoded)
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @MaxAlex, I ended up using it a little bit different but that answer really helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to MaxAlex answer I ended up using this in my code:

```
export const authProvider = {
  // authentication
  login: ({ username, password }) => {
    const request = new Request(
      process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/users/login',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ email: username, password }),
        headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
      },
    );
    return fetch(request)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
          throw new Error(response.statusText);
        }

        return response.json();
      })
      .then((auth) => {
        const { id, name, email, exp, iat } = jwtDecode(auth.token);
        if (!id || !name || !email || !exp || !iat) {
          throw new Error('Invalid token');
        }
        if (exp < iat) {
          throw new Error('Token expired');
        }
        localStorage.setItem(
          'auth',
          JSON.stringify({
            ...auth,
            id,
            fullName: name,
            email,
            exp,
            iat,
          }),
        );
      })
      .catch(() => {
        throw new Error('Network error');
      });
  },
```

Comment: A small note, if one of the required fields is missing in the token
an exception will be raised already during destructuring: const { id, name, email, exp, iat } = jwtDecode(auth.token);